# How to access the clicked element of class

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have buttons **inside for each loop** which will generate automatically when the product is added so i cannot use id to access
So using the class name in java script to access fire the click event but when i click on the button only first one gets fired

```
**HTML CODE**

<button type="button" id="remove_item"><i class="fa fa-times remove">
</i>Remove</button>

**JS CODE**

<script>
$('.remove').click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

     $('#decideModal').modal('show');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `.click()` with `.delegate()` function:

```
$(document).delegate('.remove', 'click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#decideModal').modal('show');
});
```

And also in HTML, `id` refers to a **unique identifier**. In other words, it is against standards to have 2 elements with the same `id`. For example you can add counter to your element `id` in `foreach()` loop.

Comment: I have tried to add this code but now also the first element gets removed

Comment: The code above shows only the modal view if the button is clicked. Look for the error in the callback function of your remove function.